# Get the count of records for table with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

Persons:

```
person_id   |   name    | 
-------------------------
1           |   John    |
2           |   Adam    |
3           |   Elen    |
-------------------------
```

Orders:

```
order_id    |   person_id   |   product     | 
---------------------------------------------
1           |       1       |   TV          |
2           |       1       |   Radio       |
3           |       1       |   toothbrush  |
4           |       2       |   mp3 player  |
5           |       2       |   watch       |
6           |       3       |   ps 3        |
---------------------------------------------
```

Now I need to query above tables to get the following result:

```
person_id   |   name    |   order_count |
-----------------------------------------
1           |   John    |       3       |
2           |   Adam    |       2       |
3           |   Elen    |       1       |
-----------------------------------------
```

I tried something like:

```
SELECT u.person_id, u.name, COUNT(o.order_id) FROM persons AS p LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON (p.person_id=o.person_id);
```

unfortunately this doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Persons.person_id, Persons.name, p.order_count 
from Persons
inner join (select person_id, count(*) as order_count from Orders group by person_id) p
on Persons.person_id = p.person_id
```

If you need also get that persons, who doesn't have any orders, then use `left join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT persons.id, persons.name, COUNT(orders.id) AS order_count  FROM orders LEFT JOIN persons ON (persons.person_id=orders.person_id) GROUP BY persons.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

"select o.person_id,p.name,count(o.person_id) as order_count from `tblorders` o 
Join `tblpersons` p on o.person_id=p.person_id
group by o.person_id,p.name"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select o.person_id,p.name,count(o.person_id) as order_count from tblorders o 
Join tblpersons p on o.person_id=p.person_id
group by o.person_id,p.name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.person_id, p.name, o.cnt
from Persons p
left join 
(select person_id  , count(order_id) as cnt from Orders group by person_id) o
on p.person_id = o.person_id
```